# SVG() returns null in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, svg, jsfiddle

I wanted to learn some SVG and though JSFiddle would be the perfect place to play around with it.  I'm getting `null` returned by the intial `SVG('whatever')` call.  Is this something I'm missing/doing wrong, or something wrong with JSFiddle?

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/85gsveLd/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id='canvas'><div>
```

And the JS:

```
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
  initialize()
}
else {
  window.addEventListener('load', initialize)
}

function initialize() {
  var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300,300)
  var rect = draw.rect(100, 100)
}
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of null
```

Note, I'm linking in svg.js v3.0.13 as a dependency.

**Update:** my code was based on a working JSFiddle example of an older version of svgjs.  So, using the old code with the new svgjs version caused my errors.  The lesson here was to always ensure your code targets the correct version of the library you're trying to use.

Comment: `var draw = SVG().addTo('#canvas').size(300, 300)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.13/svg.js` in your ressource in your jsfiddle to use `SVG(...)`

And then `var draw = SVG().addTo('#canvas').size(300, 300)`

Comment: `.addTo(...)` is what I needed.  Note in my question that the resource is already linked.  Otherwise `SVG(...)` itself would be undefined.

Comment: @Steverino It is undefined in the link above. I don't see it linked anywhere in the fiddle.

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle.  Not sure why it didn't retain the resource on my first attempt, or if I made a mistake.  All testing has been done with v3.0.13 linked.